# Call stored proc using xml output from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Under a tight deadline and I know I can figure this out eventually but I don't have much time to do it on my own.

I have a table that has columns for customer id and account number among many other additional columns.  There could be many accounts for a single customer (Many rows with the same customer id but different account number).

For each customer in the table I need to call a stored procedure and pass data from my table as xml in the following format.  Notice that the xml is for all of the customers accounts.

```
<Accounts>
 <Account>
  <AccountNumber>12345</AccountNumber>
  <AccountStatus>Open</AccountStatus>
 </Account>
 <Account>
  <AccountNumber>54321</AccountNumber>
  <AccountStatus>Closed</AccountStatus>
 </Account>
</Accounts>
```

So I guess I need help with 2 things.  First, how to get the data in this xml format.  I assuming I'll use some variation of FOR XML.  The other thing is how do I group by customer id and then call a sproc for each customer id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work.  This is one of the few cases for cursors.

```
create table #a (CustomerID int, AccountNumber int, AccountStatus varchar(max))

insert into #a values (1,12345,'Open')
insert into #a values (1,54321,'Closed')
insert into #a values (2,77777,'Open')
insert into #a values (2,88888,'Closed')

DECLARE @CustomerID int
DECLARE @accounts xml

DECLARE CurInvoice CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID 
    FROM #a  

OPEN CurInvoice

FETCH NEXT FROM CurInvoice INTO @CustomerID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

    set @accounts = (
    select AccountNumber,AccountStatus
    from #a
    where CustomerID = @CustomerID
    for xml path('Account'), root('Accounts'))

    exec MyProc @XmlInput = @accounts


FETCH NEXT FROM CurInvoice INTO @CustomerID
END
CLOSE CurInvoice
DEALLOCATE CurInvoice
```